# Using Type Nats to create a type level list (having problems adding numbers on the type level)

Tags: haskell, types

Just for fun, I wanted to create a Type level list that knows how long it is.  Something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import GHC.TypeLits

data family TypeList a (n::Nat)

data instance TypeList a (0) = EmptyList
data instance TypeList a (1) = TL1 a (TypeList a (0))
data instance TypeList a (2) = TL2 a (TypeList a (1))
data instance TypeList a (3) = TL3 a (TypeList a (2))
```

But, of course I'd like to generalize this to something like:

```
data instance TypeList a (n)   = TL3 a (TypeList a (n-1))
```

But this generates an error:

```
    TypeList.hs:15:53: parse error on input `-'
    Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Another attempt:

```
data instance TypeList a (n+1) = TL3 a (TypeList a (n))
```

Also generates an error:

```
    Illegal type synonym family application in instance: n + 1
    In the data instance declaration for `TypeList'
```

I assume something like this must be possible.  It's definitely possible using the notation:

```
data Zero
data Succ a
```

But I can't figure it out with the nicer looking version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type-level `Nat` improvements have landed in GHC 7.8 and this is now possible!

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, TypeOperators #-}

import GHC.TypeLits

data family List (n :: Nat) a
data instance List 0 a = Nil
data instance List n a = a ::: List (n - 1) a

infixr 8 :::
```

using `List` is just as natural as any `[]`-like data structure you'd write yourself:

```
λ. :t 'a' ::: 'b' ::: 'c' ::: Nil
'a' ::: 'b' ::: 'c' ::: Nil :: List 3 Char
```

Comment: When I've tried to use the type-level `Nat` stuff in 7.8, the problem I ran into was that while it now works for fixed finite Nats (e.g. it can work out that `List (0 + (1 + (1 + 1)))` is `List 3 Char`), when you try to write generic operations like `<++> :: List n a -> List m a -> List (n + m) a` you get errors like `Could not deduce (((n1 + m) + 1) ~ (n + m)) from the context (n ~ (n1 + 1))`. So it seems like there's still more work needed before it can really replace the Zero/Succ based approaches - although I'm far from expert, so maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3):

As they are in GHC 7.6, type-level Nats won't let you do this sort of thing. There's currently more or less no relation between the types `0 :: Nat` and `1 :: Nat`, despite what the names suggest (unlike, say, your `Zero` and `Succ Zero`, which you can do useful things with). This is going to be better in future versions of GHC.

Comment: Is that the plan for 7.8, or is it not exactly spelled out yet?